# How to send and receive an UNIX datagram with socat?

Tags: linux, unix, socat

I need to send a UNIX datagram to an open port in a running application with socat. When the application receives the datagram, it will answer back with another.

I need to do this to get the resulting datagram in a bash script. What I have found to almost work is:

```
socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/app-port.sock
```

Where `app-port.sock` is the listening port of the application which is running as a daemon.

By using `-` I could send from the STDIO the datagram, via keyboard and finally an ENTER. In the application logs I see that the datagram is being received correctly but there is no source socket/port (null), so the application can't answer back because it does not know who sent the received datagram.

Any clue on how to send the datagram with a proper source socket address and receive the answer?

Comment: Good. Keep it technical and don't mention me.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski LOL! Some kind of back alley tech advice here?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Bringing my Unsung Hero badge to the next level. You did not see this, don't say a word.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ixnay on the elphay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I made it:

```
echo 'INPUT_DATAGRAM' | socat -b 256000 - UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/dest.sock,bind="/tmp/source.sock"
```

-b option is buffer size, as the default probably is 8 KB the response datagram was being trimmed. So I configured a lot bigger one to avoid being trimmed, and worked.

Aparently by calling in this way the shell waits for the first datagram in answer, prints in screen (stdout) and then closes (it not last in interative mode). And that is what I wanted, so all OK for me.

Maybe if the server delays some seconds in the response you will need to change the default timeout with -T option. For example, for a timeout of 5 seconds:

```
echo 'INPUT_DATAGRAM' | socat -T 5 -b 256000 - UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/dest.sock,bind="/tmp/source.sock"
```

I used UNIX-SENDTO instead UNIX-CLIENT because this method seems to release the socket after the command finishes.